# CSS: How can I keep the element after an unordered list from starting on a new line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple navigation bar that has a input box.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="nav">
                <h1>Userfind</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>

                <div id="main-search">
                    <input type="text" id="usersearch" name="usersearch" placeholder="Search for User here. Must be atleast 5 characters long." required
                            minlength="5" maxlength="30" size="60">              
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But no matter what I try, I can't figure out how to keep the input box on the same line.The CSS looks like this:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#container {
  background-color: purple;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: white;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding: 0px 10px 39px;
}
#nav h1 {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
}
#nav a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #404040;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav p {
  float: left;
}
#nav #main-search {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

If I put the div "main-search" in the unordered list it stays on the same line. But how can I get it it to stay on the same line without putting in between the `<ul>` tags?

Comment: Why don't you want to add it as a <li> ?

Comment: Block elements are not inline elements they don't go on the same line. If you want them on the same line you should use `display: inline-block`.

Comment: which one would I change to inline-block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer by any means. But it includes some of the suggestions from the comments. I changed #nav li to display: inline-block, along with removing some of the conflicting css that you had.

I suggest doing the search feature as an li, or doing all nav links as separate divs using display: flex (aka flexbox).

There's a short tutorial below that you can adapt to your case:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-fully-responsive-navbar-with-flexbox-a4435d175dd3/

Your code that I added display: inline-block and removed some conflicting css:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main2.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="nav">
                <h1>Userfind</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>

                <div id="main-search">
                  <div>
                    <input type="text" id="usersearch" name="usersearch" placeholder="Search for User here. Must be atleast 5 characters long." required
                            minlength="5" maxlength="30" size="60"> 
                  </div>           
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#container {
  background-color: purple;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding: 0px 10px 39px;
}
#nav h1 {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav a {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav p {
}
#nav #main-search {
  margin-left: 27%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: couldn't get the code to work, but the flexbox worked perfectly, thanks!